# Reading HTML into XAML TextBlock

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, wpf, xaml

I have a webform where users are submitting articles that contain **bold** text, *italics* text, links, images, etc. It is being stored into `nvarchar(MAX)` data type.

I am able to pull the information in the same format as it was submitted on a web site (`ASP.NET & C#`), this is how I do that:

**ASP.NET**

```
<textarea runat="server" class="form-control" id="summernote" name="summernote"></textarea>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick=" btnSave_Click" />

<asp:Button ID="btnGet" runat="server" Text="Get" OnClick=" btnGet_Click" />
<div runat="server" id="body"></div>
```

**C#**

```
//inserting data into DB
//getting data from DB

//assigning text I got to div
body.InnerHtml = rdr.GetSqlString(rdr.GetOrdinal("Body"));
```

My problem is, that the article being submitted into the DB is being submitted in this type of format:

```
<p><span style="font-weight: bold;">This is bold text</span>. <span style="font-style: italic;">This is italics text.</span> This is normal text. <a href="http://www.google.com">This is a link</a>&nbsp;</p>
```

Basically it is being submitted in markup - which is fine, but I have one problem. I am trying to pull this information into a `TextBlock` inside of my Windows 10 application (Universal Web Application), but it is coming in as `HTML` and `TextBlock` is `XAML` and I feel like it is not going to mesh well...

This is my XAML:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="myBody"
       RelativePanel.Below="myViews"
       RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
       RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
       LineHeight="24" 
       TextWrapping="Wrap"
       Foreground="Black"
       Margin="0,20,0,20"/>
```

**C#**

```
myBody.Text = retrievedHTMLBody;
```

My question is, is how can I display the information (same format that it was submitted in on the web form) in the `TextBlock` the same way that it is displaying in my `DIV`? I do not have a problem pulling the data in, but it is setting the textblock text to the format(bold, italics, links, etc.) the same way I am able to set it in my `DIV` that is throwing me for a loop...

Comment: You're looking for RichTextBox/Block. Might give a peek at something like [this](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2010/08/31/A-Rich-HTML-TextBlock-for-WPF.aspx) before you go too far down the rabbit hole. There's others also but I don't remember any of them, haven't done this in some time.

Comment: What is the easiest way to plug that line of markup I included into the RichTextBlock to see if it is interpreting it correctly?

Comment: And that way looks really extensive... This has had to of been done before....

Comment: @ChrisW. Ended up finding a solution, thank you for your input again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution. It is to use a `Webview` and bind the HTML to it using `NavigateToString`

**XAML**

```
<WebView x:Name="myWebView" Visibility="Visible"/>
```

**C#**

```
string htmContent = @"your html goes here";
myWebView.NavigateToString(htmContent);
```